# matching between two different structured python lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, match

I use python 2.7 and I have 2 lists, one is of this shape:

```
t1 = [('go', 'VB'), [('like', 'IN'), [('i', 'PR')]], [('to', 'TO')], [('there', 'RB')]]
```

the other is in a text file stored in this format:

```
t2 = [go:VB, [like:IN, [i:PR]], [to:TO], [there:RB]]
```

I would like to see if ( t1 ) is matching ( t2 ) or not.

A problem that I face is that the ones inside the text file without ( '' ) so they looks like variables.

Can you please help in finding a way of matching these two.

```
def match(t1, t2):
    #check here if the nested lists match or not.   
    return True
```

I tried to turn ( t1 ) to string and delete ' ( '  and ' ) ' by replacing them with an empty ''
then replace ' , ' with ' : ' but it has given a lot of quotation marks and I thought this is not a great idea of fixing this issue.

Comment: Is it really `t2 = [go:VB, [like:IN, [i:PR]], [to:TO], [there:RB]]` or is it `t2 = "[go:VB, [like:IN, [i:PR]], [to:TO], [there:RB]]"' (with "" around the list)?

Comment: I am still unclear as to how you want to compare. Because ideally, I would flatten out the list and then compare them. Also, you tell the shape, do you mean that the first type `t1` is a list that is available at Python Shell interpreter?

Comment: t2 is stored among many similar inside a text file in the same shape:
{ [go:VB, [like:IN, [i:PR]], [to:TO], [there:RB]] , 
.... 
....
....
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your structure is composed only of lists and tuples containing two strings, the following function should do what you whishes by generating your target string recursively :

```
def format_list(l):
  res = "["
  items = []
  for item in l:
    if isinstance(item,list):
      items.append(format_list(item))
    elif isinstance(item,tuple):
      items.append(item[0] + ':' + item[1])
  res += ", ".join(items) + "]"
  return res
```

Comment: Exactly !! 
now it will be easier to compare between this and the one with VARIABLES in it. I should just put an if-statement to check if the seconde argument is 'VB', 'PN', 'RB' then replace it with a variable, and this will match  [A, [like:IN, [B]], [to:TO], [C]]

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not using `eval()` which is a really insecure thing.

1. use `str` to convert your `t1` to string.
2. delete all whitespaces in `t1` and `t1` with help of `replace`
3. use [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re)'s `sub` for conversion of `t2`.
4. finally, compare strings

```py
### 1
t1 = str(t1)

### 2
t1 = t1.replace(" ", "")
t2 = t2.replace(" ", "")

### 3
t2 = re.sub(r"(\w+):(\w+)", r"('\1','\2')", t2)

### 4
print(t1 == t2)
```

---

**Edit**

If you want to support tabs and newlines, you need to do this

```
### 2
t1 = "".join(t1.split())
t2 = "".join(t2.split())
```

Comment: This is a good, straightforward answer of bringing t2 to be equal to t1, I really like the way of simplifying the problem in clear steps. My preference is to bring t1 to be equal to t2, as (actually) t2 is something similar to this one but some of nested lists replaced to Variables.

Answer (score 1):

A naive and simple approach - use [`regex substitution`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to transform the string from the file to a Python evaluable form, then evil [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) it:

```
import re

s2 = '[go:VB, [like:IN, [i:PR]], [to:TO], [there:RB]]'

# 'go:VB' -> '("go", "VB")'
s2_pyth = re.sub(r'(\w+):(\w+)', r'("\1", "\2")', s2)
# '[("go", "VB"), [("like", "IN"), [("i", "PR")]], [("to", "TO")], [("there", "RB")]]'

l2 = eval(s2_pyth)
# [('go', 'VB'), [('like', 'IN'), [('i', 'PR')]], [('to', 'TO')], [('there', 'RB')]]

if l1 == l2:
    # or whatever more specific comparison
```

I think, using `eval` in this context (seems to be a harmless academic NLP task) is ok. If the tokens in your text file aren't strictly alphanumerical, you might need a smarter regex as `r'\w+'` to match them, maybe sth. like `r'[^\[\]]+'`...

Comment: I do not need split ( '=' ) as I am not going to include t2 and t1 ( just the lists) , I will try it

Comment: Ok, that simplifies my answer :)

Comment: Wow! That is great of coming from t2 to t1 !! BUT What about the other way round??

As Actually I have t2 written in another similar way but I present it like this to make it more understandable. 

My (t2) has replaced the tuples that have in its second argument either the tags 'VB' or 'PR' or 'RB' to VAIRABLES. So actually t2 for this is [A, [like:IN, [B]], [to:TO], [C]]. If there is a way of going from t1 to t2 it would be greater.

Comment: Well, if those files have random structures you enter more complicated parsing territory. If those files are generated, you should think about using some serializer that you can use to create and read the files, like JSON (see the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html))

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. It simplified the problem for me by using the power of regexes. Thaks again.